# Module property RootWebOnly

Tags: module

We are deploying file using VS project --> module.

In the elememts xml file there is an option for **RootWebOnly = true/false**. What happens if we set it to:

a.  true

b.  false

```
<Module Name="MasterPage" Path="MasterPage" RootWebOnly="TRUE" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
    <File Url="mymaster.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" >
    </File>
  </Module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Optional Boolean. TRUE if the files specified in the module are
>   installed only in the top-level Web site of the site collection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms460356(v=office.15).aspx

Really meaning that the files will only be added to the RootWeb even if they are added through a web scoped feature

Comment: What is the default value of this? And at web scope feature if set to false then it will get deployed to the specific websites library right?

Comment: yes, if applicable. I'm not sure of the default value but I would guess it is FALSE